# Can't turn off two-factor authentication for my Heroku web hosting account, even by using the command line instructions

Tags: web-hosting, authentication, heroku, password

I got a new phone and didn't save the recovery code. One day, when I tried to log in to the Heroku platform using my email and password, Heroku redirected to the https://verify.salesforce.com/v1/verify/ page and asked me to perform multi-factor authentication and enter verification code.

I can't. I found this documentation: [Recovering from lock-out](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/two-factor-authentication#recovering-from-lock-out)

What I have tried:

1. Contact the support account-lockout@heroku.com via email, ask them to disable my multi-factor authentication.
   I provided my login email and password to them. But they always reply to me like this:

   > Sorry, the email address you are using has not been recognized as a Heroku account.
   >
   > Please log in and submit a ticket via help.heroku.com where we'll be happy to help. If you are unable to log in, please send an email from your registered Heroku account.
   >
   > If you do not have a Heroku account and need support, you can create an account in seconds.
   > We apologize for any inconvenience!
   >
   > The Heroku Team
   > https://heroku.com
2. The documentation said:

   > If you have a valid CLI session on your computer, you can use the CLI to turn off two-factor authentication with the command `heroku 2fa:disable`. Here too, you will be asked for your password.

   So I tried to disable multi-factor authentication using heroku CLI.

   ```bash
   ☁  heroku 2fa:disable
   (node:42222) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED   environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
   Disabling 2fa on novaline@aliyun.com... ?
   Password: ************
   Disabling 2fa on novaline@aliyun.com... done
   ```

   Looks like it worked. But when I tried to log in to the Heroku platform again, it still redirected me to the multi-factor authentication page - https://verify.salesforce.com/v1/verify/

Am I the only one with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku does not recognize emails because I did not use the mailbox I used as my login account, that is, `aliyun` mailbox, but I used Gmail.

If your Heroku account is `example@gmail.com`, you need to use Gmail logged in with the same email to contact the support.

After doing this, you will receive a reply from Heroku support.

[image]